# SharePoint Powershell snap-in Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is missing

Tags: powershell

I have a weird error. I am trying to get my SharePoint development computer setup and it has been a horrific experience. I was able to get my SharePoint instance installed properly. When I run powershell normally all is fine and I can access the SharePoint powershell commands, but I need to provision the SecurityTokenService for SharePoint. I right clicked on the management shell and clicked Run As Administrator and it states the below error.

Add-PsSnapin: The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" is not installed on this machine.

I really don't understand why when running as an adminstrator it cannot find it but when I run it normally it does find it.

I am lost at the moment on what to do.

Comment: are you running the Windows powershell or SharePoint powershell? try to run the SharePoint powershell..Start > all program > Microsoft SharePoint products > sharepoint 2013 management shell

Comment: I right click on SharePoint 2010 Management Shell and click run as administrator and I get the error. When I just open it. it runs correctly but I can't perform actions that require administrator priviledges

Comment: this is weird, try this link;http://vintentou.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/error-the-windows-powershell-snap-in-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-is-not-install/

Comment: I tried that link already and it actually screwed the powershell for sharepoint. I had to uninstall SharePoint and reinstall to get it to work. also note that I am using windows 8.1

Comment: You installed SharePoint on Windows 8.1? this is not supproted...people still able to install it but i recommend, use the Hype V feature of Windows 8.1 Pro and build VM.

Comment: How would I develop using Visual Studio with debugging capabilities.

Comment: Ok I will just create me a new environment on a server os

Comment: once you install Hype-V and create the VM their,follow the instructions here for building the sharepoint farm with VS.http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/10/create-a-scripted-sharepoint-2013-development-environment-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: Server OS, you all set then

Comment: We used a server os in class so I bet that's why they didn't have any issues.

Comment: yes, SharePoint 2010 supported on windows 7 for development but sharepoint 2013 MSFT stop that and now forcing for VMs or Window azure for this :)

Comment: i just add the comments in answer if you like then mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, You installed sharepoint on windows 8.1, which is not supported by MSFT, that's why you see these kind of weird issue. Poeple still able to install the sharepoint with some hack but you will not get 100% from it.

Although in previous version, MSFT Support Sp2010 on win 7 but they stoped it in 2013. Now their appraoch is either using the Hype-V on windows 8.1 Pro or higher or use the windows azure for development.

here is a blog which help you build a dev farm.

http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/10/create-a-scripted-sharepoint-2013-development-environment-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: Thank you this helped me resolve my issue and save hours of headache ha-ha... Thanks Buddy